# Count inflight messages in Redis

Tags: redis, py-redis

I'm using Redis as a simple pubsub broker, managed by the redis-py library, using just the default 'main' channel. Is there a technique, in either Redis itself or the wrapping Python library to count the number of messages in this queue? I don't have deeper conceptual knowledge of Redis (in particular how it implements broker functionality) so am not sure if such a question makes sense

Exact counts, lock avoidance etc. is not necessary; I only need to check periodically (on the order of minutes) whether this queue is empty

Answer (score 0):

Redis Pub/Sub doesn't hold any internal queues of messages see - https://redis.io/topics/pubsub.

If you need a more queue based publish mechanism you might to check [Redis Streams](https://redis.io/topics/streams-intro). Redis Streams provides two methods that might help you [XLEN](https://redis.io/commands/xlen) and [XINFO](https://redis.io/commands/xinfo).